# Перенос стилей из 2-ух файлов .vue в один

Tags: vue.js

Есть две практические одинаковые страницы(одинаковые стили), отличаются незначительно, на второй есть пара уникальных блоков.
Структура  следующая:

```
<template>
....
</template>

<script>
//vue.js code like export default {name: 'Page1', .... and other
</script>

<style scoped>
...
</style >
```

Можно ли перенести классы стилей в один файл и подключить к двум `.vue` файлам?
Правильно ли я понимаю что можно использовать миксины `vue` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Миксины для логики. Стили можно подключить двумя способами:

1)

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import './style.scss';
</style>
```

2)

```
<style lang="сss" src="./style.css"></style>
```